# How to Scroll QTableWidget automatically to the selected item

Tags: qt, c++14

As I am building application to play music but I have multiple tracks which I had stored in QTableWidget but now when I click the play button which is listed in the each column for song to get played now I need to change the play Icon to pause so as to identify which song is currently playing for that I had updated the whole layout of tracks and its works fine but when I play some which is listed below like 20th number song then when my layout get reloaded then its start from top so again I need to scroll down which is creating problem when I have 100 of records so is there any way to get auto scroll to that particular item ?? or some other way to do this without reloading a layout ???
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Using `setCurrentItem` should last to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

From Qt's [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#scrollToItem) we can find the following:

> `void QTableWidget::scrollToItem(const QTableWidgetItem *item, QAbstractItemView::ScrollHint hint = EnsureVisible)`
>
> Scrolls the view if necessary to ensure that the item is visible. The hint parameter specifies more precisely where the item should be located after the operation.

Should do the trick.

**UPD:**

If you need  to change *one* icon, you don't really need to update the *whole* layout, it would be wrong to make concrete assumptions without seeing your code but updating only one row *must* be possible anyway.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion how to update only the single row ?
which is being clicked ??

Comment: Well, if I were you I'd use `QTableView`, to begin with. It requires some model class, but implementing it is pretty simple and in the end you'd be able to write something like `myModel->setData(someIndex, QIcon('...'), Qt::DecorationRole)` to set icons in cells, you may also probably use `QStandardItemModel` without writing a custom one. But even in your case there exist: `void QTableWidget::itemClicked(QTableWidgetItem *item)` or `QTableWidgetItem *QTableWidget::item(int row, int column) const` + `void QTableWidgetItem::setData(int role, const QVariant &value)`. Why not to use any of those?